# Oracle constraint to allow particular value once per foreign key value

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, ddl

Let's say I have a table `parent` with primary key `id`, and a table `child` with foreign key `parent_id` and a "boolean" column (constrained to a 0 or 1), let's call it `is_initial`.

What I want to do is put a constraint on `child` so that for a particular value of `parent_id`, there can be only one row with `is_initial = 1`.  There can be any number of rows with is_initial = 0.

Can this be done with a constraint?  I prefer not to add a trigger.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go, I believe I understand what you are looking for now

Note the change in the unique index:

```
create unique index childTable_initialIndex on childTable(
  case when is_initial = 1 then parent_id 
  else null
  end);
```

### Ammended Code

```
create table childTable(parent_id number, child_id number primary key, is_initial number, somethingelse varchar2(50) );

create unique index childTable_initialIndex on childTable(
  case when is_initial = 1 then parent_id 
  else null
  end);


  insert into childTable(parent_id, child_id, is_initial,somethingelse) values (1,1,0,'works');
1 rows inserted.  

  insert into childTable(parent_id, child_id, is_initial,somethingelse) values (1,1,0,'will not work if childId is pk');
SQL Error: ORA-00001: unique constraint (SYS_C0062138) violated
00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
           For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
           this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
*Action:   Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key  

  insert into childTable(parent_id, child_id, is_initial,somethingelse) values (1,2,1,'works3');
1 rows inserted.  

  insert into childTable(parent_id, child_id, is_initial,somethingelse) values (1,3,1,'should not work');
SQL Error: ORA-00001: unique constraint (CHILDTABLE_INITIALINDEX) violated
00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
           For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
           this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
*Action:   Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key.  

  insert into childTable(parent_id, child_id, is_initial,somethingelse) values (2,4,0,'works4');
1 rows inserted.

  insert into childTable(parent_id, child_id, is_initial,somethingelse) values (2,5,0,'works5');
1 rows inserted.

  insert into childTable(parent_id, child_id, is_initial,somethingelse) values (2,6,1,'works6');
1 rows inserted.

  insert into childTable(parent_id, child_id, is_initial,somethingelse) values (2,7,1,'should not work');
SQL Error: ORA-00001: unique constraint (CHILDTABLE_INITIALINDEX) violated
00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
           For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
           this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
*Action:   Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key.  
  --we should only see things that work
  select * from childTable
/ 

--this should not work, since works already has the 1/1 is_initial 1
update childTable 
   set somethingelse = 'Should not work!'
     , is_initial    = 1
 where somethingelse = 'works';

SQL Error: ORA-00001: unique constraint (CHILDTABLE_INITIALINDEX) violated
00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
           For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
           this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
*Action:   Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key.
```

Here are the results:

```
PARENT_ID CHILD_ID IS_INITIAL SOMETHINGELSE                                    
--------- -------- ---------- --------------------------------------------------
        1        1          0 works                                              
        1        2          1 works3                                             
        2        4          0 works4                                             
        2        5          0 works5                                             
        2        6          1 works6
```

Comment: @hmqcnoesy what version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: +1 Thanks for going the extra mile here.  I guess the difference between yours and mine is that I was not repeating values for `child_id`.  I was using that as a pk on the child table.  So all your insert statements would work if your `child_id` values were unique.

Comment: @hmqcnoesy I changed it to make the unique index on the Parent_ID when the is_initial=1 (see above)

Comment: Yes, that's what I came up with as well, and it works the way I want, thanks to you and Chris.  Your diligence is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with a unique index:

```
create unique index initialindex on child(
  case when is_initial <> 1 then parent_id || 'xx' || child_id 
       else null
  end
);
```

Now after you try to insert a second row with is_initial = 1 you should get a constraint violation.

Comment: nice approach, however I believe that you want is_initial=1 and not is_initial<>1

Comment: +1 Thanks for this clever answer. **But** if `child_id` is unique, this doesn't constrain anything.  Right?

Answer (score 2):

Do it in a more "relational" way - don't use `child.is_initial`, instead use `parent.initial_child_id` that can be NULL, and is FOREIGN KEY toward the `child` table.

Since `initial_child_id` is in the `parent` table and not in the `child`, there can naturally be only one per parent.

Your DDL would look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
    id INT,
    initial_child_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE child (
    child_id INT,
    parent_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (child_id)
);

ALTER TABLE parent ADD FOREIGN KEY (initial_child_id) REFERENCES child;
ALTER TABLE child ADD FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parent;
```